# Initializing a list with a type yet to be determined

Tags: java, generics

I was realy hoping you could help me with something.
For my Java course, I need to design a generic array builder.
That would not be a problem, but for some stupid reason, I'm not allowed to know what type of object my List should contain, until after it gets initialized.

I know I can make it a list of objects, but the content should maintain its properties.

The code below shows aproximately what every method should do.

```
public class ArrayListBuilder<T> implements IBuilder<T> {

private ArrayList<T> content;

public ArrayListBuilder<T>(){
    content = new  ArrayList<T>();
}

public static ArrayListBuilder make() {
    return new ArrayListBuilder();
}

@Override
public void add(T t) {
    content.add(t);
}

@Override
public Collection<T> result() {
    return content;
}
```

The could will primarily be used in a Zip class, that creates a new list from two old ones.

Thanks in advance,
Traz

EDIT: My problem Is the following: My T is completely random, and the new list must know it holds T objects, for the purpose of methods targeting said objects. But I can't tell the ArrayList what it will contain at it's creation.

Is there a way To initalize it with a type T, and later change it completely and let the class know, that instaed of a Collection of Ts it should now return a Collection of some other type?

```
ArrayList<Pair<Integer,String>> zipResult1 =
zip(ArrayListBuilder.make(), Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(”4”,”5”,”6”));
```

The given code shows some of the requirements, As you see, the make() method, mustn't contain a type declaration, and still deliver paies of Integers and Strings.

Comment: "*but for some stupid reason, I'm not allowed to know what type of object my List should contain*" correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that the whole idea about generic types? Anyway you forgot to describe problem you are facing. Are you getting any errors or wrong results?

Comment: @Pshemo "correct me if I'm wrong" sounds a little rethorical in this context :)

Comment: @Mena I always could misunderstood something (English is not my first language ;)

Comment: @Pshemo fair enough. The frustration of not knowing the parametrized type at runtime seems common with folks starting with generics. At least it was for me!

Answer (score 0):

So, what exactly are you having problems with? Your code is already almost complete; what's missing is that the factory method `make` is not generic. It needs to have a type parameter too:

```
public static <T> ArrayListBuilder<T> make() {
    return new ArrayListBuilder<T>();
}
```